# I keep getting invalid syntax in python. I have checked with PEP8 and it says there is no error

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
print("hello new player")
myName = input("what is your name?")
print("myName")
myVAR = input("Would you like to start a new game?Yes/No")

if(myVAR == "Yes")
    print ("you are good")
elif(myVAR == "No")
    print ("Good bye")
exit
```

There is a red line after `if(myVAR == "Yes")`

Comment: DO accept my answer if you think it has solved your problem

Answer (score 3):

you are missing colon `:` after the `if` statement

```
if(myVAR == "Yes"):
                  ^
```

and the `elif` statement

```
elif(myVAR == "No"):
                   ^
```

Also you are using `exit` which should be `exit()`. You should not use it in programs, but in the interpreter only

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `:` after `if`, and for some reason, [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) throws an error but it works with [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), here is a code which works:

```
print("hello new player")
myName = raw_input("what is your name?\n")
print(myName)
myVAR = raw_input("Would you like to start a new game?Yes/No\n")

if(myVAR == "Yes"): # Added ":"
    print ("you are good")
elif(myVAR == "No"): # Added ":"
    print ("Good bye")

exit
```

I added `\n` at the end of the prompt string in order to show the prompt on a new line.

Here is the result:

```
$ python test.py 
hello new player
what is your name?
Chill
Chill
Would you like to start a new game?Yes/No
Yes
you are good
```